# Looking for YA fantasy about reincarnation

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm looking for a Young Adult fantasy romance about reincarnation.

A woman travels back in time where there was a forbidden romance between a monk and herself. She is incredibly beautiful. She's bricked up as punishment for her affair with the monk. Forward in time, she finds they married each other's reincarnations.
I thought the book was called **Evergreen** but I have had not luck finding it under that title.
I Read this during 70s.

Comment: There is a time-travel book called _Evergreen Crossing_, but does not have a similar plot.

Comment: Is the song 'Greensleeves' mentioned?

Comment: I don't remember the song--could be. Must have read the story in '75 or thereabouts. Story begins in the present. The heroine is sitting by the pool. She flashes back to another incarnation where she is a peasant girl and is in love with a monk or priest who tries to save her from being bricked up because of their relationship. Ends happily in the future when she realizes her husband is the incarnation of the priest she loved so much. Set in medieval Europe...I remember the novel was green--could swear the title was "Evergreen." Thanks for any help. It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Ah! I may have found it! [Green Darkness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Darkness) by Anya Seton. The Wikipedia link includes cover art, if that will help confirm the identity.

Comment: I have also been trying to find this book again for years and also believed the name wss "Evergreen". Is this 'Green Darkness" the one?